# Modificar enlace tomando texto de la propia URL generada por tipeo libre

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo una inquietud, sobre algo que necesito disponer para difusión.
Si alguien me puede ayudar le agradezco. Estuve revisando las preguntas y lo que mayoritariamente encontré es a la inversa, que es generar enlaces con variables.
En este caso el  enlace que estaría en el cuerpo se completa con el texto libre escrito en la URL.

La URL es así

http://miweb.com/?h=

```
<a href="?clickh1="></a>
```

y el enlace a completar es

y todo lo que se escriba despues del = en la URL se completa igual después del = en el enlace, al actualizar.

Como ejemplo si me dirijo a esta URL

```
 http://miweb.com/?h=Juan
```

El enlace se completa así

```
 <a href="?clickh1=Juan"></a>
```

Muchas gracias

Asi anduvo bien. Gracias

```
    <a href="d" onclick="location.href=this.href+'?key='+h;return false;">Link</a>
         
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var h = location.search.split('h=')[1]
    </script>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. En realidad Juan va a recibir ese link ya con su nombre, no lo va a tipear. Va a hacer clck sobre él y se abrirá el navegador y tendrá su  codigo perzonalizado con los enlaces propios.

Answer (score 1):

Por que no lo haces asi?

Una funcion que tenga la url base y un input para completarla.

```js
function redirectTo() {
    const url = "http://miweb.com/?h=";
    let param = document.getElementById('completar_url').value; 
    window.location.href = url + param;
}
```

```html
<input id="completar_url" type="text" />
<button>
    <a onclick="redirectTo();">pulsa aqui</a>
</button>
```

Comment: Me fué muy útil la respuesta, el caso es que la ejecuto tal cúal , pero la url de destino no es una constante, porque tengo tres botones. quisiera agregar un valor, que puede ser un  <a href:"nombre_de_una_carpeta" onclick="redirectTo();"> , entiendo que eso se puede agregar aquí window.location.href = url + param;  Gracias